# Holonomic constraints as a limit of the motion under potential

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, mathematical-physics, constrained-dynamics, complex-systems

In *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*, Arnold states the following theorem without proof in pages 75-76:

> Let $\gamma$ be a smooth plane curve, and let $q_1, q_2$ be local coordinates where
> $q_1$ parameterises the curve and $q_2$ is the coordinate in the orthogonal direction to the curve. Consider the system with potential energy
> $$ U_N = Nq_2^2 + U_0(q_1, q_2). $$
> and let $\varphi(t, N)$ be the evolution of $q_1$ under this potential when the system has initial conditions
> $$q_1(0) = q_1^0,\quad\dot{q}_1(0) = \dot{q}_1^0,\quad q_2(0) = 0,\quad\dot{q}_2(0) = 0 .$$
> Then we have that the limit $\psi(t) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \varphi(t, N)$ exists, and $q_1 = \psi(t)$ satisfies Lagrange's equation
> $$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L_{*}}{\partial \dot{q}_1} = \frac{\partial L_{*}}{\partial q_1} $$
> with the Lagrangian
> $$L_{*}(q_1, \dot{q}_1) = T|_{q_2 = \dot{q}_2 = 0} - U_0|_{q_2 = 0}.$$

Arnold writes that the proof is based on the fact that $q_2^2 \leq c N^{-1/2}$ for some constant $c$, which is not difficult to see.
The answer previously given [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/504985/) to a similar question claims that the dynamics for $q_1$ then does not depend on $\dot{q}_2$, so that the claim follows from continuity of solutions with respect to a parameter.

Now, Arnold never mentions what $T$ is, apart from saying that it is the "kinetic energy of motion along $\gamma$".
I assume that it is the standard kinetic energy $T = \frac{m}{2}\langle\dot{x}, \dot{x}\rangle$, and Arnold indeed seems to indicate this when he describes the generalisation of this result to arbitrary surfaces.
It seems to me that the decoupling claimed in the answer to [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/504985/) would depend on $T$ instead being chosen as $T = \frac{m}{2}\langle \dot{q}, \dot{q} \rangle$, which is dependent on the parameterisation of $\gamma$.

My interpretation of the $q$ coordinates is as follows: letting $x = (x_1, x_2)$ be Cartesian coordinates in the plane, we have a (local) parameterisation $\gamma = \gamma(q_1)$ of $\gamma$, and we define local curvilinear coordinates $x(q) = \gamma(q_1) + q_2 n(q_1)$, where $n(q_1)$ is a unit vector orthogonal to the tangent at $q_1$, $\gamma'(q_1)$.
Thus, assuming that $q_1$ is arc length,
$$ \dot{x} = (1 - k(q_1)q_2)\gamma'(q_1)\dot{q}_1 + n(q_1)\dot{q}_2, $$
where $k$ is the signed curvature of $\gamma$.

Hence, with $T = \frac{m}{2}\langle\dot{x}, \dot{x}\rangle$,
in terms of the $q$-coordinates we get
$$T(q, \dot{q}) = \frac{m}{2}(1 - k(q_1)q_2)^2\dot{q}_1^2 + \frac{m}{2}\dot{q}_2^2. $$
This means that, contrary to what is claimed in the answer given in [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/504985/),
there will be $\dot{q}_2$ terms in the equation of motion for $q_1$, which is
$$ m a(q)\ddot{q}_1 + \frac{m}{2}\frac{\partial a}{\partial q_1}\dot{q}^2_1 
+ m\frac{\partial a}{\partial q_2}\dot{q}_1\dot{q}_2 = -\frac{\partial U_0(q_1, q_2)}{\partial q_1}, $$
where $a(q) = (1 - k(q_1)q_2)$.
Note that
$$ \frac{\partial a}{\partial q_2} = -2(1 - k(q_1)q_2)k(q_1), $$
so this term does not go to zero in general.

Now $\dot{q}_2$ does not seem to converge to zero: in fact, adding an infinitely strong potential $Nq_2^2$ would rather induce oscillations in $q_2$ of frequency of order $N$, which
means that $\dot{q}_2$ is only bounded (I think this follows from conservation of energy), so using some continuity result in this way seems to be hard.

We do have that $a(q_1, q_2 = 0) = 1$, so that the Lagrangian converges to $L_{*}$ along the trajectories with the given initial conditions.
Can one use this to prove Arnold's theorem rigorously? We can make as strong assumptions about $U_0$ as we like.

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4888963/11127